# How can I scrape google scholar using key words in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, google-scholar

I'm trying to measure the variation in the number of publications for different species. There is an R package that does this called [specieshindex](https://github.com/jesstytam/specieshindex) but I'm having trouble getting it set up. I was wondering if there is something I could do with current google scholar scrapers?

The idea would be to input the species name, e.g. Homo sapiens, and get details like number of papers, number of citations etc.

Hope you can help.